# Rails and href in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am attempting to follow along with a tutorial for creating an Evernote-clone but running into trouble with this section on line 5 that is supposed to link back to a document. When I attempt to run it it gives me a TypeError in Docs#index and 'no implicit conversion of Doc into Integer':

```
.wrapper_with_padding
    #docs.clearfix
        -unless @docs.blank?
            - @docs.each do |doc|
                %a{href: (url_for[doc])}
                    .doc
                        %p.title= link_to doc.title
                        %p.date= time_ago_in_words(doc.created_at)
                        %p.content= truncate(doc.content, length:50)
        -else
            %h2 Create Doc!
            %p Start Creating Documents and Organizing Your Life!
            %button= link_to "Create Doc", new_doc_path
```

Comment: use to_s method to convert in string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change line:5 to -

```
%a{href: (url_for(doc))}


%a{href: (url_for[doc])} # this will give you following error
#=> ActionView::Template::Error (can't convert Doc into Integer):
```

Refer [url_for](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor/url_for)

Answer (score 0):

`url_for[doc]` should be `url_for(doc)`